# Play framework 2.3.7 compile fail with StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I want to compile a simple example using Play framework 2.3.7 but I got `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The details output are:

```
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/mcor/dev/dc-eventsys-play/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[debug] Getting compiler-interface from component compiler for Scala 2.11.1
[debug] Getting compiler-interface from component compiler for Scala 2.11.1
[debug] Running cached compiler 2124a1e9, interfacing (CompilerInterface) with Scala compiler version 2.11.1
[debug] Calling Scala compiler with arguments  (CompilerInterface):
[debug]     -deprecation
[debug]     -unchecked
[debug]     -encoding
[debug]     utf8
[debug]     -bootclasspath
[debug]     /home/mcor/dev/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/resources.jar:/home/mcor/dev/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/mcor/dev/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/home/mcor/dev/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/home/mcor/dev/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/jce.jar:/home/mcor/dev/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/home/mcor/dev/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/home/mcor/dev/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/classes:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar
[debug]     -classpath
[debug]     /home/mcor/dev/dc-eventsys-play/target/scala-2.11/classes:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/twirl-api_2.11/jars/twirl-api_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/jars/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.11/bundles/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/build-link/jars/build-link-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-exceptions/jars/play-exceptions-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.javassist/javassist/bundles/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-iteratees_2.11/jars/play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-stm/scala-stm_2.11/jars/scala-stm_2.11-0.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.2.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11/jars/play-json_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-functional_2.11/jars/play-functional_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-datacommons_2.11/jars/play-datacommons_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/joda-time/joda-time/jars/joda-time-2.3.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.joda/joda-convert/jars/joda-convert-1.6.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.3.2.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/bundles/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty/bundles/netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.netty/netty-http-pipelining/jars/netty-http-pipelining-1.1.2.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.6.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/jars/logback-core-1.1.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/jars/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j_2.11/jars/akka-slf4j_2.11-2.3.4.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/xerces/xercesImpl/jars/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/javax.transaction/jta/jars/jta-1.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-jdbc_2.11/jars/play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.jolbox/bonecp/bundles/bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.h2database/h2/jars/h2-1.3.175.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/tyrex/tyrex/jars/tyrex-1.0.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/anorm_2.11/jars/anorm_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.jsuereth/scala-arm_2.11/jars/scala-arm_2.11-1.4.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.plugins/scala-continuations-library_2.11/bundles/scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-cache_2.11/jars/play-cache_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/jars/ehcache-core-2.6.8.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-ws_2.11/jars/play-ws_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-16.0.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/com.ning/async-http-client/jars/async-http-client-1.8.14.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/oauth.signpost/signpost-core/jars/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/oauth.signpost/signpost-commonshttp4/jars/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.0.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.0.1.jar:/home/mcor/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2643
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:199)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.SourceFile.lineToString(SourceFile.scala:44)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.InternalPositionImpl$class.lineContent(Position.scala:168)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.Position.lineContent(Position.scala:12)
    at xsbt.DelegatingReporter.makePosition(DelegatingReporter.scala:67)
    at xsbt.DelegatingReporter.convert(DelegatingReporter.scala:58)
    at xsbt.DelegatingReporter.info0(DelegatingReporter.scala:42)
    at scala.tools.nsc.reporters.Reporter$$anonfun$error$1.apply$mcV$sp(Reporter.scala:69)
    at scala.tools.nsc.reporters.Reporter$$anonfun$error$1.apply(Reporter.scala:69)
    at scala.tools.nsc.reporters.Reporter$$anonfun$error$1.apply(Reporter.scala:69)
    at scala.tools.nsc.reporters.Reporter.withoutTruncating(Reporter.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.reporters.Reporter.error(Reporter.scala:69)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CompilationUnits$CompilationUnit.error(CompilationUnits.scala:132)
```

I skip the remaining part of the stacktrace because its very long. Anyone has encounter the same problem before or know how to solve it?

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_25

activator-1.2.12
```

I have try to revert to last commit and it work, then I try to add my change and it fail. git status show:

```
modified:   app/controllers/Application.scala
new file:   app/models/Models.scala
new file:   app/views/list.scala.html
modified:   conf/application.conf
modified:   conf/routes
```

Comment: From stacktrace, I conclude you have a compilation error that compiler is trying to report `CompilationUnits$CompilationUnit.error` and `Reporter.error` but it fails due to `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Try finding errors in your project.